# Rake task replies with undefined method `created_at' – can't access columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason I cannot access columns in tables through ActiveRecord using a rake task. My rake task looks like this:

```
task :reminder => :environment do
  User.all.each do |user|
    if user.entries.last.created_at.strftime("%A, %d of %B %Y") == 3.days.ago.strftime("%A, %d of %B %Y")
      UserMail.reminder(user).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

On execution, I am getting back `NoMethodError: undefined method 'created_at' for nil:NilClass`. However, when I am not using `created_at` but simply `user.entries.last` I don't get an error. This shows that the connection is established (thanks to `:environment`).

What could possible be wrong that I can't access the `created_at` column of the table? Any other column name that exists doesn't work either.

Comment: It's very probable that `user.entries.last` returns `nil` for a certain `user`. Ruby can't call a method on a `nil` object, hence the error. It does not mean that you don't have a `created_at` column in your db table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with `created_at`. Most likely some of your users do not have any entries, so `user.entries.last` is `nil`, and `nil` does not have a method called `created_at`. If you want to send the reminder to all users without entries, you should change your condition as follows:

```
if user.entries.empty? || user.entries.last.created_at.strftime("%A, %d of %B %Y") == 3.days.ago.strftime("%A, %d of %B %Y")
```

Or, if you don't want to send a reminder to users without entries:

```
if !user.entries.empty? && user.entries.last.created_at.strftime("%A, %d of %B %Y") == 3.days.ago.strftime("%A, %d of %B %Y")
```

Both should work without exceptions.

Comment: Oh snap! You're totally right, thanks so much. That was silly. :)